# Variable scope inside forEach

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an exercise to sort people from `ancestry`, an array of record objects, into the centuries they lived in and their age of death.

Here's the final code, which works as intended:

```
ancestry.forEach(function(person) {
  // this works with ages inside or outside forEach **
  var ages = {};
  var century = Math.ceil(person.died / 100);

  if (century in ages) 
    ages[century].push(person.died - person.born);
  else
    ages[century] = [person.died - person.born];
});
```

Basically it just calculates which century a person belongs to and creates a key value pair like this with the age of death in an array:

```
{
16: [24, 51, 16]
17: [73, 22]
18: [54, 65, 28]
}
```

What I don't understand is why `var ages = {};` can be declared both inside and outside of forEach and the result is the same? Shouldn't `function(person)` create a new `ages` each time it is called within `forEach`?

Comment: *"Shouldn't function(person) create a new ages each time it is called within forEach?"* If you tell it to, yes. otherwise, no. As written `ages` won't exist outside the foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only use the value of `ages` inside the function.

You assign a value to it. You then modify the object that is that value. You then copy the values of properties of that object elsewhere. Then you never care about that object until you give it a new set of values on the next loop around (at which point you only care about the new values).